# How a transaction is verified in a blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, policy, nonce, consensus

If a miner A creates a block containing a transaction A and a miner B creates a block NOT containing the transaction A about at the same time, then some of the other miners will first receive the block of the miner A and the others will receive the block of the miner B.

If the chain of the miner B grows faster than the chain of the miner A, then the transaction A will never be accepted (like it never happened). So, how the user A who created the transaction A can be sure that the transaction A was accepted/verified by the blockchain?

Also, is there a possibility that the transaction A is verified by the blockchain at some point and then in the future another subchain not containing the transaction A will grow faster, thus rejecting transaction A ?

Are there any time checkpoints created that all the miners should agree upon ?

Comment: Which chain exactly are you considering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: Since blockchains are all very different, I'll assume we're talking about Bitcoin.

If block B is mined first, transaction A goes back into the mempool (memory) of the nodes and is candidate to be included in the next block. The mempool kicks transactions out after 2 weeks if they have not been mined.

It is possible that another chain not containing the block could grow faster, but highly unlikely because each block takes 10 min on average and miners are incentivized to work on the main chain (as opposed to a forked chain) so they would switch over immediately when the main chain mines a new block. They would not be working on a forked chain for long enough to outpace the network, wasting time and resources. It requires at least 51% (on average) the hashpower of the network to outpace the main chain and is called a 51% attack. This has never happened to Bitcoin, but has happened to smaller chains like Bitcoin Gold for example.

Comment: In an hypothetical scenario where this does happen to bitcoin (51% attack), would that mean that the transaction would be lost ? If so, how a user could check if his transaction was lost (it does not belong in the main chain anymore) ? Is there a pre-configured policy  if something like this happens ?

Comment: If the transaction was mined previously, and then that chain was discarded (in the 51% attack scenario), that transaction must be submitted again (because it's outputs could have been spent, so it may be invalid on the new chain). This is why some custodians/exchanges require a minimum number of confirmations (with each additional block after the transaction was first confirmed, it gets exponentially harder to attack).